# this sequence $A_{n}$ have recursive relations?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Let $$A_{n}=\sum_{i=0}^{n-3}(-1)^{n+i-2}\dfrac{13n^2-31n-10ni+9i+i^2+16}{(3n-i-3)(3n-i-4)(2n-i-3)!\cdot i!}$$

I want find the $A_{n}$ recursive relations,such as following form
$$A_{n}=B_{n}+C_{n}A_{n-1}+D_{n}A_{n-2}+\cdots$$
I have try sometimes,and can't find it,can you help me?

This question has been asked on MSE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1070762/how-find-this-sequence-recursive-relations) without receiving any answers.

Comment: By general theory, your sequence has to satisfy a recurrence of the desired form where the coefficients are polynomials in $n$. Let $a_n=(2n+3)!A_{n+3}$. See next comment...

Comment: Then experimentally, $2^4 (n+2) (n+3) (2n+3) (2n+7) (27296942n+96266479) a_n +$ $2^3 (n+3) (1373740004n^4 + 11974782476n^3 + 36773573779n^2 + 46446616891n +$ $19095420600) a_{n+1} - 2^2 (n+4) (1258873802n^4 + 12734573713n^3 +$ $46301208703n^2 + 68411873198n + 30162171666) a_{n+2} + 2 (n+5) (1272271211n^4 + 21664023114n^3 + 138039728785n^2 + 392255730894n +$ $423165299544) a_{n+3} - (n+6) (169792631n^4 + 623043934n^3 - 19045733677n^2 -$ $151948512276n - 311659470468) a_{n+4} -$ $3 (n+7) (3n+19) (3n+20) (3057095n + 14424538) a_{n+5} = 0$ for all $n \ge 0$.

Comment: See the book "A=B" by Petkovsek, Wilf and Zeilberger for background and ways of deriving such recurrences in concrete cases: http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html.

Comment: +1 for bringing people's attention to that brilliant (though, alas, so far totally useless for my favorite kind of "formal algebra" questions) text again.

Comment: A small correction: the coefficient of $a_{n+5}$ has a factor $(n+7)^2$ instead of $n+7$.

Comment: The (likely) recurrence above suggests that considering $b_n = (n+2) a_n = (n+2) (2n+3)! A_{n+3}$ might simplify the computation (the degree of the coefficients in the recurrence goes down from 5 to 4).

Comment: @MichaelStoll,Thank you for give this usefull reslut

Comment: @math110: I should perhaps clarify that I have not actually *proved* the recurrence, I have only checked it for $n$ up to 490 or so. This is certainly very strong evidence that it is true, but does not constitute a proof.